# Optimal RAM for Akka

Tags: akka

I'm testing akka-cluster, running several nodes on single laptop. Each java process consumes ~900 mb. Is it okay for Akka? If yes, what is recommended memory for a production node?

Answer (score 1):

900Mb is plenty for Akka to run in, but whether it's enough for you depends on the specifics of your application.

When running under load have a look at the memory use in VisualVM and see how frequently and how long garbage collections take. This will let you know whether to increase the amount of heap space used by the JVM.

You can configure the initial and maximum heap size at startup...

```
-Xms128m -Xmx256m
```